# Shortest distance between two skew lines

Tags: 3d

I was studying elementary 3D geometry in that I read about shortest distance between two skew lines but in that the fact was used that the shortest distance between two skew lines is given by any line joining them multiplied by $\cos\theta$

Where $\theta$ is the angle between shortest distance and the random line which is considered above.

Everything is fair but I am not able to understand how the relation of two lines by cosine it's true and how to prove it

Comment: Just a hint: the $\cos$ comes from the dot product which is used for projections. It holds $$\vec a\cdot\vec b=|\vec a|\cdot|\vec b|\cdot\cos \angle(\vec a,\vec b),$$ where $\angle(\vec a,\vec b)$ means the angle between $\vec a $ and $\vec b$ and might be $\theta$ in your case.

Comment: How can you say that the projection of  first would be exactly same I mean they maybe very large or very small

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand this question *at all*.